# How to get post data of a form using Selenium Web Driver

Tags: selenium

I need to get the value of an action of the form element.
For example, for the form:

```
<form action="/MyApp/Users/Index" method="post"></form>
```

I would like to get the "`/MyApp/Users/Index`" value.

I tried using the `.GetAttribute("action")` method of the `IWebElement` but it returns an empty string.

Comment: wow ... what does it return if you do the same on "method" ? (just curious)

Comment: Can you do it directly in javascript, eval it, and return the value

Comment: Shame on me... just figured out I had more than one `<form>` tags on my page... the `GetAttribute` works fine.